# How to cast KeyValuePair passed as Parameter to Command_Executed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command, eventargs

Seemingly simple concept but can't get past this.

I have a Command...the _Executed method receives a KeyValuePair (types don't matter) as it's Parameter.

```
myCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyValuePair<System.Type, MyCustomArgs> kvp = e.Parameter as KeyValuePair<Type, MyCustomArgs>;
:
:
:
}
```

Can't do that as it's non-nullable.  How do I accomplish this?  I want to extract the KeyValuePair from e.Parameter.

Appreciate any insight and will happily post more code/information if necessary.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to put into the KVP. What is in e.Parameter?

Comment: e.Parameter contains a combination of System.Type, CustomEventArgs.  I have multiple view_models which post back to a Main View model.  I have a Button which has Command="NextPage" CommandParameter="{Binding NextPageToLoad}".  NextPageToLoad returns a KeyValuePair that reads as KeyValuePair<System.Type, MyCustomArgs>.  I need to extract the KeyValuePair from e.Parameter in the above Method.

Comment: (KeyValuePair<Type, int>)e.Parameter?

Comment: I figured it out.  Two things...  1. KeyValuePaur is a struct.  I made it nullable.  2.  The casting you posted above USIA correct.  I could not use an "as"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use an explicit cast, rather than an implicit one, as you have done.
Implicit cast:

```
KeyValuePair<System.Type, MyCustomArgs> kvp = e.Parameter as KeyValuePair<Type, MyCustomArgs>;
```

Explicit cast:

```
KeyValuePair<System.Type, MyCustomArgs> kvp = (KeyValuePair<System.Type, MyCustomArgs>)e.Parameter;
```

Comment: Just a little note. They both are explicit. Implicit meas you dont write any syntax and cast happens automatically. Eg when going from lower precision to higher. (int b = 4; float c = b;)